# How to pass data into header while using URLSession in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, urlsession

I am new to swift and am in the learning phase.

I have to basically make a request using URLSession but the API does not allow any unauthorized requests

here is my code :

```
func getCoinPrice(for currency: String) {
    
    let urlString = baseURL + currency
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        let dataAsString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        print(dataAsString ?? "NO VALUE")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I have the line **request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "CoinAPI-Key")** where I am passing the APIkey but strangely I always get this response

```
{
  "error": "You didn\u0027t specify API key or it is incorrectly formatted. You should do it in query string parameter \u0060apikey\u0060 or in http header named \u0060X-CoinAPI-Key\u0060"
}
```

The same request in header works perfectly in Postman as you can see below
[image]

what am I doing wrong? any help would be appreciated

modification of code (still get same error) :

```
func getCoinPrice(for currency: String) {
    
    let urlString = baseURL + currency
    
    var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: urlString)
    
    urlComponent?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: apiKey, value: "x-api-key")]
    
    let request = URLRequest(url: urlComponent!.url!)
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        let dataAsString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        print(dataAsString ?? "NO VALUE")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell with the code you posted `"CoinAPI-Key"` or `"x-api-key"`? Which one are you using? Try `"X-CoinAPI-Key"`

Comment: Strangely, the error is saying that in headers it should be under `X-CoinAPI-Key` key, not `x-api-key`

Comment: @Larme And OP said `"CoinAPI-Key"` as well as `"x-api-key"`

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant with the "X-" (ie, as said in the error) which doesn't seem to be in the test done by the author. Then, i was intriguing about how it worked on Postman.

Comment: I have tried all 3 "x-api-key" , "CoinAPI-Key" and "X-CoinAPI-Key" I get the same error for all 3 @Larme

Comment: It says X-CoinAPI-Key for header key or apikey for param key, does you're problem solved?

Comment: There are 2 methods for passing the API key to us, you only need to use one:

Custom authorization header named X-CoinAPI-Key
Query string parameter named apikey

I also saw this in their documentation

Comment: Could you generate Swift Code (not really Swifty, but compiling) from Postman, and check if it works, then compare with your own code? Else, show what's the Postman generated `cURL`? And lastly, print `request.allHeadeersFields` just to be sure that the API Key is correct (no "Optional()" or soùehting like that (but I'd had expect an other error then).

Comment: @RezaKhonsari can you explain in code how I would do so?

Comment: @Larme the swift code generated from Postman is the same with only one extra line 
request.httpMethod = "GET"
I added this line but still got same error

Comment: in you're postman image you are using https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com but in you're comments you mention you are using CoinAPI?
which one are you using?

Comment: bitcoinaverage are using different method for authentication their clients

Comment: I tried using both  https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/BTC and https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD in both when I pass value by header I get the same error

Comment: @junaidtariq updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

ok approach you're answer with this solution

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still get the same error in response

Comment: Could you please share you're code after modification, or update you're question with my answer

Comment: check now I've modified my question and added new code

Comment: @junaidtariq check my answer now

Comment: It's still not working for me. did you test your scenario with 

https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTC

because I get this response

Unauthenticated requests are not allowed. Take out a new plan or start a free trial at https://pro.bitcoinaverage.com

Comment: @junaidtariq no I'm using with this service: https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchanges/

Comment: I'll use this service then. I think bitcoinaverage services are broken. Thankyou for all your help. I have accepted your answer

Comment: You're welcome, for more info please check their documentation

Answer (score -1):

This has probably long since been answered, but you never set a value for the apiKey variable in your code.

urlComponent?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: apiKey, value: "x-api-key")]

Your line here is using the apiKey variable, but you don't have a line prior to it (or at least in the code shared) that says something along the lines of:

let apiKey = "Your api key here"

You could probably replace your line of code to read like:

urlComponent?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "Your API key here", value: "x-api-key")]

which would likely also resolve your issue (if it hasn't been figured out already that is).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but please keep in mind when asking a question on stack overflow things have to be broken down into their simplest form. I am very well aware of storing secret data like API keys in env files. 

your entire post here is irrelevant